# How do you fix error exception for access violation?

Tags: c++, exception, assembly, x86

I am a little confused as to what I need to fix to handle the error Exception thrown at 0x00AFF748 in ProjectTwo.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00AFF748.

I am attempting to write an external assembly language program that is then called by a C++ program. I am unsure if I messed up the assembly language code and that is why I keep getting the error. The goal of my program is

```
int problem1_ ( )
{
int numberArray [4] = {1, -3, 12, 15};
 int result = 0, index = 0;
int numElements = 4;
while (index < numElements)
{
if ( index >= 1 && numberArray[index] > 2 )
{
result = result * numberArray[index] ;
}
else
{
 result = result - 5;
}
index++;
}
return result;
}
```

My C++ Code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

extern "C" int problem1_();

int main()
{
    //Declare the variable and set it to returned result
    //From calling the assembly program
    int x = problem1_();

    //Print the results
    cout << "The result is: "<< x << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

My assembly Language code:

```
.model flat, c


.data
numberArray DWORD 1, -3, 12, 15
numElements DWORD 5

.code
problem1_ proc
mov eax, 0                      ;value of eax is 0
lea ebx, numberArray            ;Load the array's memory address into register ebx'
mov ecx, numElements            ;ecx is count down counter
cmp ecx, 0                      ;If ecx not greater than 0, jump to quit
jng FINISH

iterateThruArray:
cmp[ebx], eax                   ;Compare value at current index to eax
jl result1
jmp result2

result1:
mul numberArray
jmp FINISH

result2:
sub eax, 5 
jmp FINISH

FINISH:
 pop ebp                        ; pop ebp from the stack
 ret                            ; return to calling program


problem1_ endp
end
```

Comment: How do you fix access violation? Just don't violate access. A very likely probability is accessing an array beyond it's bounds. So first up, debug your code to ensure you aren't doing that.

Comment: The actual AV is probably due to calling `pop ebp` without ever having done a `push`.  But there are so many other problems here, I scarcely know where to start.  But @TheUndeadFish is right that you're going to want to run this thru a debugger.  At least it might result in better questions.